# Revert to a state - Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, restore

I'm looking to make software tests that include installing services etc.
For that would be nice to install Windows 7 and find a way to restore to a previous state and be able to install software again like if I hand't install anything before.

I would love to hear your guys opinions on this, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can *use a Sandbox.*  Use a program like **[Sandboxie](http://www.sandboxie.com/)** for application isolation...

> Sandboxie runs your programs in an isolated space which prevents them from making permanent changes to other programs and data in your computer.

You can *install a virtual machine*, and test software inside of the VM, thus you won't mess up your host system at all.  Options include **[VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/)**, **[VMWare Player](http://www.vmware.com/products/player/)**, **[XP Mode/Virtual PC](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/)** (limited to Ultimate and Business editions of Windows 7)...

Comment: +1 for suggesting VMs. Most virtual machines support taking "snapshots" of the harddrive and rolling back changes. This would be an ideal usage scenario for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[System Restore](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/products/features/system-restore)**.  works well, has saved me many times...

> Creating a Steady State by Using Microsoft Technologies
>
> *Explains how to replicate Windows SteadyState actions by using Windows 7 features and free tools from Microsoft.*
>
> http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=ef232619-7600-4768-b111-f60ba13862ea

A paid alternative to Windows Steady State (SS does not work on Win7 systems):

> Wondershare Time Freeze
>
> http://www.wondershare.com/pro/time-freeze.html

You could also **image your drive** after installing Windows 7 but before installing programs, this way you can restore Windows 7 to its original state before software. Use free software like **[DriveImage XML](http://www.runtime.org/driveimage-xml.htm)** (highly recommend!).

> [Hot Image Your PC's Hard Drive with DriveImage XML (Lifehacker)](http://lifehacker.com/326086/hot-image-your-pcs-hard-drive-with-driveimage-xml)

Comment: Isn't system restore for system files only? I don't even want to keep user data :))

Comment: Oh and SteadyState is planned to be discontinued, at least that's what Microsoft says.

Comment: yes, notice that I said that. you can use it legally long afterwards.

Comment: @Canha: what about virtual machines?

Comment: Could also be an option! Feel free to enhance your answer :p Tip: Virtualbox would be nice.

Comment: @studiohack what do you mean "what about virtual machines?" How would VMs be any different. Unless your talking about backing up a vm state. Depending on what software you are using for VMs. If you use VMWare (i.e. VSphere 4) you can take a snapshot of you virtual machine, and as long as you do not change your VMs HDD size, you're fine. If you do try to change the HDD size, it will tell you "no."

Comment: @David: I'm talking about testing software and such *inside* of a virtual machine, this way, he does not mess up his host OS.

Comment: @Canha: see 2nd answer - there were so many options as to answer this question, i just split up the answers...

Comment: @studiohack I see... Nvm then. I thought you were wondering about something off topic. lol